# A difficulty in understanding why $\ell_{2}^D$ is not complete.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\ell_{2}^D$ be the subspace of $\ell_{2}$ consisting of all sequences {$\lambda_{k}$}, where $\lambda_{k} = 0$ for all but at most a finite number of $k$.

In the following picture:
[image]

In the third line why the summation of the series is $\frac{1}{2^m}$?

In the fifth line why the given Cauchy sequence converges to $x = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^2},....)$?

Could anyone explain the previous 2 points for me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the thrird line, let $L$ be sum of series. Then
$L=\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \implies 2^mL=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}= \frac{1/2}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1$. Thus $L=\frac{1}{2^m}$.
For the fifth line,sequence $x_m$ converges to $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^2},.....)$ which can be seen from the third line by replacing $x_n$ by $x$,taking $m$ goes to $\infty$.
EDIT:
  $||x-x_m||= \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^m} \to 0$ as
$m \to \infty$

Comment: your justification for the fifth line is not clear for me, could u please write it in  details?